# Php mail send with isset

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I am creating an external form to insert on a wordpress page but I have a problem on mail sending.
I have some  on the form and used some if's to get the values like

```
if ($select==1)
{
$select=option1;
}
```

And at the end of the form instead of submit I am printing it to the browser, everything is working so now I am trying to get that data to a mail() but on the prints to the browser I used some issets that I dont know how to use on mail()
Example of prints:

```
    echo "<b>Nome: </b>$name<br>";
    echo "<b>NIF / NIPC: </b>$nif<br>";
    echo "<b>Endereço de E-mail: </b>$email<br>";
if (isset($solicitacao)){
    echo "<b>Solicitação: </b>$solicitacao<br>";
}
if (isset($selecionado)){
    echo "<b>Solicitação: </b>$selecionado<br>";
}
if (isset($eterceiro)){
    echo "<b>E-mail do terceiro: </b>$eterceiro<br>";
}
if (isset($texto)){
    echo "<b>Observações: </b>$texto";
}
```

Variables like name,nif,email I can mail() them simply but what can I do with the others? is there any way to isset on the mail?

Comment: maybe you are trying to use html mail. you have to set those in a variable instead of echo.  `$mailbody="HTML CONTENT";`

Comment: im trying to use this one mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg); the problem is that $msg will have this variables that change with people's choise on <select>

Comment: If the name, NIF and email address are working correctly, the rest should be too. If none of it's working, maybe you want to be adding things to the end of `$msg` instead of echoing them?

Comment: I just used echo to see if I get all values, what I want to do now is put all the data I echo into a $msg but there is some variables that I want to insert only if exists

Comment: there are several ways to doing like: `$msg="begin from here..."; if (isset($solicitacao)){
    $msg .= "<b>Solicitação: </b>$solicitacao<br>";
}; $msg .= " and so on..." ` you can add additional text at end of your variable by `.=`

Comment: Thats it ! So I can use if isset on $msg? nice